# Can't install ionic on node.js

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, installation, npm-install

I can't install ionic framework due this error:

[image]

I use win 10
Node.js version 7.4
Npm version 4.0.5

Just installed npm without problems
Also installed cordova without problems

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with node version over 7, try with version 6.9